# Angular router-outlet overwrites page

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-module

I work on a larger application with lots of reusable parts that aren't really all that reusable yet. What I have in mind is creating a module for dialogue windows, that decides what kind of a dialogue window it wants to show and displays everything accordingly on top of the original page where that dialogue has been initiated. The problem here is that these original pages themselves have queryParameters, such as usernames. I suspect my problem lies exactly there -> the router link redirects to the dialogue module and its corresponding component, thereby robbing the original component of the necessary queryParams, which causes the router-outlet to completely navigate away from the original page instead of showing the content in the outlet.

I'm on Angular 12.

Below is the code of the parent component's .ts file, this is where it gets it queryParams from:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
) {
  this.routeSub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(data => {
    this.username = data.username;
  });
}
```

In the corresponding .html file, the link looks like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./dialogue']" [queryParams]="{username: username}">123456789</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The route I redirect FROM is: 'localhost:xxxx/original-component?username=123456789'
The route I redirect TO is: 'localhost:xxxx/original-component/dialogue?username=123456789'

I would expect this to display the component INSIDE the router-outlet of the original page, keeping the rest of its content, but it redirects completely. I have checked which life-cycle hooks get activated, and indeed, when using the routerLink, the ngOnDestroy of the original component gets triggered. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the route reuse strategy.

Comment: Was thinking about that and even tried implementing it. But it seems really complicated and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use params instead of queryParams, this would solve the issue

parent.component.ts

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
) {
  this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(data => {
    this.username = data.username;
  });
}
```

in HTML

```
<a [routerLink]="['./dialogue',username]">123456789</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You must also set a route with param, in your route module

```
{ path: 'dialogue/:username', component: ParentComponent }
```

Comment: This won't let any part of the app know the content I want to be showing in the outlet is the dialogue component. In the route module, you wrote:
{ path: 'dialogue/:username', component: ParentComponent }, thereby removing any reference to the dialogue component. The routing now changes the URL correctly, but without actually navigating to the dialogue. How do I make it so that it actually redirects me as well as not overwrite the parent component?